# What is the time complexity of counting?

Tags: dictionary, time-complexity, counting

I have a list of `n` books, for example, `books = ["1984", "Harry Potter", "Hamlet"]`.

Also, I have a list of lists, where each inner list represents someone who has read some of the books (possibly all or none of them), possibly `0` or multiple times, so, for example, I can have something like `readings = [["1984", "Harry Potter", "Harry Potter"], ["Hamlet", "Harry Potter"], [], ["Hamlet", "Hamlet", "Hamlet", "Hamlet"]]`.

For `readings` I need to count how many times each books is read. This seems like a trivial operation in terms of coding (create a dictionary of `title : number of readings`, iterate over each inner list and increment the value in the key-value pair), but I struggle to understand the complexity of that count.

**Idea №1**: Since there are `n` books, the time complexity is `O(n)`

**Idea №2**: Since there are `n` books and `m` people in `readings`, the time complexity is `O(nm)`

**Idea №3**: Since each book can be read finite number of times, for example, `n` times, `n^2` times or even `n^n` times, I have no idea what the time complexity is, because I do not know which is the maximum power of `n` that we should choose here, looks like it goes to infinity.

So what is the time complexity of counting how many times all the books are read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary approach you suggest sounds like a good idea. If we can assume that dictionary access is a constant-time operation, the number of books in the list (`n`) will be irrelevant.

The time complexity for the algorithm you describe would be *O(k)*, with *k* being the total size of all readings. This is easy to see, if you imagine looping through all books in all readings and updating your dictionary for them.

This is true regardless of what else you know. And without more information about the size of this list, you cannot obtain a more precise expression for the time complexity of your algorithm.

However, if you do know more, you can express it in a more useful way. For example:

- If the average number of readings per person is *r*. Then, the complexity is *O(rm)*, where *m* is the number of people in `readings`.
- There is an upper bound for the number of times a person can have read the same book. If this value is bounded, it can be treated as a constant. Then, your complexity is *O(nm)*, like you suggest. (It is not likely that this bound would depend on *n*.)

It seems as if you do understand the concept of time complexity, but are just confused about how you are allowed/expected to express it.